# is there a clean way to use the id of a model after saving it to the database?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, backend

i'm in the process of learning the laravel framework, and currently i'm building a very small app that shortens valid urls to this format :
`http://localhost/374` the number represents the id of a url's model that is saved in the database .

so to get that id (which is an `auto increment` attribute) , i save the url model to the database so i can then retrieve the id and concatenate it to the base application url . my problem here is that i'm doing two queries for a single task , i don't know if that's a bad practice , but if there's a better way to do this i'm open for suggestions .
here's the controller method responsible for this process :

```
    public function shorten(Request $request)
    {
        $url =  Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'url' => 'url'
        ])->validate()['url'];

        $url_model = Url::firstOrNew(['url' => $url]);

        if ($success = $url_model->exists)

            // the model exists in the database .
            // we'll retrieve the shortend url and skip directly to displaying the view .
            $shortend_url = $url_model->shortend_url;

        elseif ($success = $url_model->save()) {

            // it does not exist, so we'll save it to retrieve the id assigned by the database .
            $shortend_url = env('APP_URL') . '/' . $url_model->id;
            $success = $url_model->update(compact('shortend_url'));
        }

        return view('result', compact('success', 'url', 'shortend_url'));
    }
```

Comment: Is the ID not assigned to your model after the successful save?

Comment: You can just use `$url_model->id` instead of using getAttribute. Either way, it's not really two queries because once you save it, `$url_model` gets updated with the current attributes.

Comment: We assume the column is an `auto increment`. Number of factors, RDBMs etc. Perhaps read up on [`lastInsertId`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) and/or look at the laravel source code to understand how it works.

Comment: @aynber but you see , after saving the model the first time , i have access to the id , wich then i use to make a shortend_url , then i update the model with this shortend_url , aren't those two queries ?

Comment: No, you can't know the ID prior to the insert. (over simplified... not getting into triggers and things). This is a valid insert/update scenario, two queries..

Comment: @ficuscr the id is indeed an `auto increment` attribute , i'm gonna update the post

Comment: Instead of doing it this way, use an [Eloquent event](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#events) on your model that will automatically update the attribute.

Comment: @aynber I did considere that but since i'm trying to get the foundations right i avoided events and middlewares and such .

Comment: This would be a case where the event would be the better way to go, though in a way it's doing the same thing here.

Comment: @aynber that's what i tought exactly , i refactored the names and the migrations to reduce boilerplate and leave everything inside the controller , that's one less class definition to worry about :v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  public function shorten(Request $request)
    {
        $url =  Validator::make($request->all(), ['url' => 'url'])->validate()['url'];
        $url_model = Url::firstOrNew(['url' => $url]);

        if (!$url_model->exists) {
            $url_model->save();
        }
        $shortend_url = env('APP_URL') . '/' . $url_model->id;
        return view('result', compact( 'url', 'shortend_url'));
    }
```

Comment: you forgot to update the model after assigning the $shortend_url

Comment: your shorten_url is a combination of your url and your modelID , there is no need to store in in the DB

Comment: oh yeah, i can't believe i missed such an obvious point , thank you .